# Where is the properties location in Android Studio 3.1.2?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am new to Android development and want to start building my own project using android studio. I do follow a tutorial from this link : 
https://stackskills.com/courses/the-complete-android-n-developer-course1/lectures/1593837

In the tutorial he did explain things on **Properties** in android studio. But as I am searching the location of **Properties** in my platform, it seems that I did not manage to find it. Please help. Thanks.

This is the view of his android studio:
[image]

As for the picture below is mine. I am using windows 7:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without clicking on any component in the component tree, you get this:

[image]

Click on `ConstraintLayout` or any other component then you will see the attributes:

[image]

Click on View all attributes(bottom right), then you will see all the attributes:

[image]

Comment: Is it that the new Android IDE, which is the one I am using the name is Attributes and not properties? Actually I want to have exactly like the one in the tutorial I am following to avoid confusion in the future. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes this is the new one, yes the name is attributes

Comment: I see it now. Thank you Peter. You are so awesome man. Thanks,